# Using the Pinterest hoverbutton but disabling it for certain images in XHTML 1.0 Strict

Tags: javascript, html, hover, pinterest, xhtml-1.0-strict

I would like to add the ability for images on my blog page to have a link to pin the image to pinterest when hovering over them.

Pinterest have a page on their helpcenter which enables you to do this.  https://en.help.pinterest.com/entries/23624997-Add-a-widget-to-your-website

I have added the code to the footer of my website, and it works fine.  The code I have added is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" data-pin-hover="true"></script>
```

The pinterest user guide suggests that where you don't want the hover button to appear, e.g. on a specific image, you amend the  tag with the following attribute:

```
data-pin-no-hover="true"
```

So in that way, an image tag would look like the following, and the hover button would not appear:

```
<img data-pin-no-hover="true" src="yourimage.jpg" />
```

I have tried to do this on my site for images which I don't want to be pinned, but it does not work.

My site, which I am developing on the squarespace platform (version 5) is in XHTML 1.0 Strict.  From the research I've been able to do, it seems that the 'data-' attribute is an HTML5 attribute, and accordingly when I try and use it, that's the reason it does not work for my site.

Does anyone know a way to get this 'data-' attribute to work in XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can still use the data-attribute as far as I know.

Something like:

```
if ($('img.class').data('pin-no-hover')) {
 $('.pinterestClass').hide();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea - i've got it working now.  I used your plan and modified it slightly to insert the attribute, and it works.  Code i used was like this:  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#p2hiddenInfo img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', 'true');
});
</script>

Comment: Thanks!!! @Christopher Marshall, answer worked for me in Wordpress. Used: jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('thumbnail img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', 'true'); });